# OMNeT++: how to debug cpp file in Inet

Tags: omnet++

I'm new to omnet++. I want to debug the file -- pingapp.cc in the picture. But I can't find the .ini file. So is there any solution to debug it? Cuz I want to take a step to debug the file and find the function call hierarchy.

[image: Debug]

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

`PingApp` is used in many examples located in `INET`. For example, take a look at `examples/dhcp/omnetpp.ini`.
To debug `PingApp.cc` set a breakpoint somewhere inside this file, then choose `Run` | `Debug Configurations...`, double-click on `OMNeT++ Simulation`, and set:

- Executable: `opp_run`
- Working dir: `/inet/examples/dhcp`
- Ini file(s): `omnetpp.ini`

and press `Debug`.

Comment: Thanks a lot.I add a breakpoint in pingapp.cc. When i debug in your way, it can't Step Over/ Step Into. It just open a window called Qtenv and begin simulation. Did I perform wrong? Hope for your answer. Thanks again. :)

Comment: Have you started simulation when Qtenv window appeared? Have you build INET in debug mode?